# CF template runs from browser, but not scheduler

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

ColdFusion 10 / Windows 2K8 R2 Standard

I have 2 scheduled tasks called for one hosted site on this server.  Both tasks run fine when called from either a local browser, or a remote browser.  Neither runs from the scheduler.  No errors are thrown nor logged.  If I manually run the task from the scheduler the message indicates it ran fine - but it doesn't.

The same CF server on the same box from the same scheduler runs 3 tasks pointed to a different hosted site on the same server and those 3 run fine.

I've even created a new template to run from scheduler that just emails me the last run time - same thing - won't run from the scheduler (either manually or via the schedule) but can copy & paste the URL into a new browser tab on the server and it runs fine.

I've deleted and reentered the tasks to no avail.  I'm not even sure where to continue trouble shooting this at this point and I'm looking for any tips or feedback to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who gets is the issue is the java keystore and the SSL certifiate.  Browser vs. schedulder cfhttp run differently and you may need to manually import the certificates into your java keystore to get it to run from the scheduler.